# How do you assign user input to be stored into arrays

Tags: c, arrays

My challenge is to write a program that will store a user's GPA as a float value in a array. The user can enter up to 30 GPA's and display the average if wanted, after each value is iuput. What I'm confused about is how to use a `scanf()` function while in a loop to store float values in an array. Can anyone explain with a sample code?

OK so this is the code that I have started. I know it's bogus but I wanted everyone to get a better idea of the program I'm trying to write. I want the user to type in how many GPA's they have. The number they input will be the number of arrays I will have.

```
#include <stdio.h>
main()
{
    int loopcount = 0;
    int NumGpa = 0;
    NumGpa = 0 - 1;
    float = 1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10,11,12,13,14,15,16,17,18,19,20,21,22,23,24,25;
    int gpa[NumGpa] ={1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10,11,12,13,14,15,16,17,18,19,20,21,22,23,24,25};
    int i = 0;
    int total =0;

    printf("\t\tWelcome to the GPA calculator.\n ");
    printf("Please enter the number of classes you have counted for you GPA: ");
    scanf("%d", &NumGpa);

    while (loopcount &lt; NumGpa)
    {
        printf("\nenter your first GPA: ");
        scanf("%d", &1); //??????????????(i want loops to use scanf() if order &2,&3 ect?

        for (i=0; i&lt;gpa; i++)
        {
            total += arbin[NumGpa];
        }

        printf(" you average gpa is %d", NumGpa / ????);
        getchar();
    }
}
```

Comment: OK SO THIS IS THE CODE THAT I HAVE STARTED I KNOW ITS BOGUS BUT WANTED EVERYONE TO GET A BETTER IDEA OF THE PROGRAM IM TRYING TO WRITE. I WANT THE USER TO TYPE IN HOW MANY GPA'S THEY HAVE. THE NUMBER THEY  INPUT WILL BE THE NUMBER OF ARRAYS I WILL HAVE.

Comment: Less bogus if you turn off the Caps Lock key. Guaranteed to make you a better programmer, too.

Answer (score 1):

When you're reading a `float` with `scanf`, you pass the address of the `float` in question. You can take the address of an item in an array about the same way as you would anything else, using the address-of operator (`&`).

Alternatively, you can simplify things just a little bit. In C, the subscript operator (`[]`) is equivalent to a pointer operation. In particular, `a[b]` is equivalent to `*(a+b)`. However, `&` and `*` are pretty much exact opposites, so in this case they'd end up cancelling each other out. As such, if you prefer you can just use `a+b`, where one of them is the name of the array, and the other is the index of the item in the array that you want to read.

Answer (score 0):

`scanf("%f",&arrayVariableName[i]);`

Comment: Minor typo -- you want `&arrayVariableName`.

Answer (score 0):

```
int i = 0; // current user
float user_gpa[NUM_USERS]; // your array

while (i < num_users) {
    scanf("%f", &user_gpa[i]); // reading data for the i-th user (%f means float)
    i = i + 1; // next user
}
```

Comment: i confused. why dident you assign (NUM_USERS) a variable number such as 30, for example why dident you include: int NUM_USERS = 0

Comment: @Arbin Because it's just an illustration, not a complete program. num_users is a goof -- it should be upper case.

Answer (score 0):

try this

```
for(i=0; i<30; i++)
 scanf("%f", arrayname[i]);
```

if you want the average directly then try this

```
float temp, ave=0;
int i;
for (i=1; i<=30; i++)
{
 scanf("%f", &temp);
 ave += temp;
}
printf("%f", ave/30);
```

Answer (score 0):

Well, there were few many mistakes in your code, Probably this might help.

```
enter code here

void main()(
    int loopcount = 0;
    int NumGpa;
    NumGpa = 0 - 1;
/*
    float = 1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10,11,12,13,14,15,16,17,18,19,20,21,22,23,24,25; i don't understand why were you doing this.
    int gpa[NumGpa] ={1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10,11,12,13,14,15,16,17,18,19,20,21,22,23,24,25};
*/
    int i = 0;
    float total =0; /this is float so that output will be accurate.
    printf("\t\tWelcome to the GPA calculator.\n");
    printf("Please enter the number of classes you have counted for you GPA: ");
    scanf("%d", &NumGpa);
    int gpa[NumGpa];
    while (loopcount < NumGpa)
    {
        printf("\nenter your %d GPA: ", loopcount);
        scanf("%d", &gpa[loopcount]); 
        loopcount++;
    }
    for (i=0; i<NumGpa; i++)
    {
        total += gpa[i];
    }    
        printf(" you average gpa is %f", total / NumGpa);
        getchar();
}
```